# Im getting this error: firebase.INTERNAL.registerAppHook is not a function, why?

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, web-applications, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am trying to setup **firebase** web client messaging.
I couldn't find this error mentioned anywhere

I have my firebase account and basic firebase code in my app. 
Authentication seems to be working, I had some errors about that and fixed them.
Now I'm trying to retrieve some info from the DB but I'm getting this error.
Yes, the DB has info in it.
Here is my code ( without the auth data, yes I have that info from my account and yes I have the container with that id setup as well )

This is js inside some PHP, seems to be loading correctly with no errors

```
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

      const preObject = document.getElementById("object");
      const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child("object");

      dbRefObject.on("value", snap => console.log(snap.val()));
```

I am getting this error and I couldn't find info about it anywhere:

> TypeError: firebase.INTERNAL.registerAppHook is not a function

I was expecting info to be retrieved and shown on site

Comment: Ok found a fix... dont use auth.js... i dont need it so I took it out

Answer (score 2):

The error is arising from the line:

```
<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

Remove it and try again!